# Get login details from input and and pass them to php file with ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this form in my html code:

```
    <form name="log">
        Username: <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="user"></br>
        Password: <input type="password" style="width: 100px" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" class="login" style="width: 150px; text-align: left" value="Log In">
    </form>
```

and this javascript to get the values and send to them to a php file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.login').on('click',function(){
           var id = document.forms['log']['user'].value;
           var password = document.forms['log']['pass'].value;
           if (id == '' || password == ''){
               alert('No username or password given');
           }
           else {
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'login.php',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: {'id': id, 'pass': password}
               });
           }
       });
    });
```

Here is the file where i want to process the data:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$user = new User($id,$pass);
```

When I call the new user class it displays an error message saying undefined index.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to include the file from which I send the data into the file that the data goes?
2. Why is the ajax call not working?
3. After I fix this how will I hide a button when user is not logged in and display it after?

Comment: your ajax code doesnt have `success` callback , you need to add one to hide your button, which will be processed when ajax call is complete successfully

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers...

1. Give a `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` to your `click()` function.
2. Replace the following:

   ```
   var id = $("input[name='user']").val().trim();
   var password = $("input[name='pass']").val().trim();
   ```
3. For hiding the button:

   ```
   success: function () {$(btnSelector).hide();}
   ```

Comment: Also do i need to include the file from which I am executing this javascript?

Comment: ok I'll see what I can do but I've been getting the same error over and over.  I would search even more thank you for your help though!!